# How to use utlizie stringbuilder to add every other character and restart at a space?

Tags: java, for-loop, char, iteration

The half string should return every other character in a string it should return the starting character. For instance, `halfOfString(“Qbkm Zgis”, 0)` returns the String “Qk gs” and the call `halfOfString(“Qbkm Zgis”, 1)` returns the String “bmZi”. Once you get to a space the letter coming after should be counted then you continue taking every other letter.

My code is not working the way it is supposed to and I've been trying to fix with different ways but a space character throws everything off.

```
 public String halfOfString(String message,int start ){
    StringBuilder halfString = new StringBuilder();
    int length= message.length();
    for (int k=start;k<length;k++){
        char achar = message.charAt(k+1);

        if (Character.isLetter(achar)!=true){
            achar='\0';

        }

        System.out.println("this is char"+"\t"+achar);
        halfString.append(achar );
        System.out.print("this is halfString in the forloop"+"\t"+halfString);

    }

    return halfString.toString();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `chatAt(k)` instead of `k+1`, and you don't need to check to see if it's a space. Also do `k += 2` instead of `k++` (As you want every other character). Lastly you don't need to resolve the length to a variable. You can just check the length directly:

```
 public static String halfOfString(String message,int start ){
            StringBuilder halfString = new StringBuilder();
            for (int k=start;k<message.length();k+=2){
                char achar = message.charAt(k);
                halfString.append(achar);
            }
            return halfString.toString();
        }
```

*Output*:

```
//with 0 as start:
Qk gs
//With 1 as start:
bmZi
```

Comment: thank you the code is right. How did you know you didn't have to check for a space? I am struggling with overthinking my code. Also I thought spaces were counted as a character?

Comment: @Eli Why would you have to check for a space? It'll be appended on just like any other `char`

Comment: in some programming languages a space is counted as a character. I'm still learning java.